# VS Add things to a newly created form

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I am trying to create a new window,

```
WinMain meniu = new WinMain();
this.Close();
meniu.ShowDialog();
```

I would like to know how can I add things like buttons on the new window and how to edit it's parameters or even a function like

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: are you trying to create and add controls dynamically or what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I have a default window with a child window and I would like to know what should I do to add controls on the child window and how to add a specific function for the child Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a windows forms sample, i've added a button after the form was created:

```
        var form = new Form1();
        form.SuspendLayout();
        var button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(279, 20);
        button2.Name = "button1";
        button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        button2.TabIndex = 0;
        button2.Text = "button1";
        button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        form.Controls.Add(button2);
        form.ResumeLayout(false);

        Application.Run(form);
```